# In a tcp connection... Java (Packets)

Tags: java, tcp, client, packets

When I have a TCP connection that uses packets.. (Server / Client Application) Should I keep sending a packet back and forth  (Between the server and client) just to see if the connection is alive or is that unnecessary? like a KeepAlive packet..

another question is does it make a huge difference (performance wise) if I send an int (DataOutputStream) though a stream instead of sending a Packet object (ObjectOutputStream) which has like an average of 5 fields at least 3 methods and some getters and setters? would it make such a big difference performance wise?

Comment: why -1? What is wrong with my thread?

Comment: Don't know either, it's a valid question. The aspect you have to consider is how embed the keepalive mechanism into your existing traffic. If you've been using an ObjectOutputStream, you should stick with that approach. Deserializing small objects from an OOS shouldnt affect your perfomance.

Comment: @Trixmix: I know nothing of the downvote, but you should know that [SO is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128554/40342) and therefore this is not a thread, but a question. ;-)

Comment: Yeah I'm used to forums thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeap. This is called heartbeat. This help recevier of heartbeat to detect if there is problem in connection. Regarding the second part, if you try to send the object than it need to be deserialize and serialze. This will surely have the impact on performance. If you want to know the performance from network lag percpective than it should not be much difference.

Comment: So if I make a pretty big game using the object stream it should not create network lag but may affect performance client side?

Comment: would it decrease performance enough to the point of barely playable even if you dedicate more ram?

Comment: Can you quickly answer my question please?

Comment: RAM has not much part to play in it. Can you clarify if you are worried due to network lag due to heartbeat or object (de)\serialization. If you are desiging the Network Game, then my suggestion will be to stick with basic datatype.

Comment: I am designing a game that would function both in singleplayer and multiplayer. I have created the basics of single player and wanted to early on implement multi player for later use. So its not like the entire game is Server/client its just the multiplayer part of it

Comment: My main concern is network lag. I can handle client performance lag.. Anyways I dont think the performance lag would be that great.. the packets are compact and ill make them as small sized as possible with the least amount of fields and methods...